# How to configure a xmpp pubsub leafnode so that anyone can publish or update item there?

Tags: xmpp, smack, node-xmpp

The user romeo@host creates a LeafNode `0c55624367fc10d2548c569782f569dc:downline` by this configuration:

```
("pubsub#deliver_payloads", "true")

("pubsub#notify_config", "false")

("pubsub#notify_delete", "false")

("pubsub#notify_retract", "false")

("pubsub#purge_offline", "false")

("pubsub#persist_items", "true")

("pubsub#publish_model", "open")

("pubsub#max_items", "50")

("pubsub#subscribe", "false")

("pubsub#access_model", "open")

("pubsub#send_last_published_item", "never")

("pubsub#deliver_notifications", "false")
```

Creates an item like this:

```
<item id='downline'>
  <downline xmlns='pubsub:mecloak:users:downline'>
    <downline>
      {&quot;users&quot;:[{&quot;username&quot;:&quot;do hdhddkd&quot;,&quot;userphone&quot;:&quot;+8801111111147&quot;}]}
    </downline>
  </downline>
</item>
```

User juliet@host tries to update/publish in the same node in this way:

```
<iq to='pubsub.192.168.0.100' id='1P42B-58' type='set'>
  <pubsub xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub'>
    <publish node='0c55624367fc10d2548c569782f569dc:downline'>
      <item id='downline'>
        <downline xmlns='pubsub:mecloak:users:downline'>
          <downline xmlns='pubsub:mecloak:users:downline'>
            {"users":[{"username":"chhy","userphone":"+8801111111147"},{"username":"do hdhddkd","userphone":"+8801111111147"}]}
          </downline>
        </downline>
      </item>
    </publish>
  </pubsub>
</iq>
```

But juliet is getting an error like this:

```
<iq xml:lang='en-US' to='+8801111111153@192.168.0.100/12934698245865334251579' from='pubsub.192.168.0.100' type='error' id='1P42B-58'>
  <pubsub xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub'>
    <publish node='0c55624367fc10d2548c569782f569dc:downline'>
      <item id='downline'>
        <downline xmlns='pubsub:mecloak:users:downline'>
          <downline>
            {&quot;users&quot;:[{&quot;username&quot;:&quot;chhy&quot;,&quot;userphone&quot;:&quot;+8801111111147&quot;},{&quot;username&quot;:&quot;do hdhddkd&quot;,&quot;userphone&quot;:&quot;+8801111111147&quot;}]}
          </downline>
        </downline>
      </item>
    </publish>
  </pubsub>
  <error type='auth'>
    <forbidden xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/>
  </error>
</iq>
```

Am I missing a point, perhaps a configuration?

Answer (score 0):

After research, I find out the problem. The problem was not within the configuration but within the item id.

```
<item id='downline'>
            <downline xmlns='pubsub:mecloak:users:downline'>
              <downline>
                {&quot;users&quot;:[{&quot;username&quot;:&quot;do hdhddkd&quot;,&quot;userphone&quot;:&quot;+8801111111147&quot;}]}
              </downline>
            </downline>
          </item>
```

> in Romeo's case the item id was downline and also in Juliet's case the id was downline

```
<item id='downline'>
            <downline xmlns='pubsub:mecloak:users:downline'>
              <downline xmlns='pubsub:mecloak:users:downline'>
                {"users":[{"username":"chhy","userphone":"+8801111111147"},{"username":"do hdhddkd","userphone":"+8801111111147"}]}
              </downline>
            </downline>
          </item>
```

> juliet has no right to override romeo's item that is why server rejects it.

juliet changed the item id and it works fine. :)